# Xamarin Intent not sending information

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.android

This activity does not send any information through the intent no matter what I try, when used in the next activity the Intent.Extras is null.
Any idea on how to solve this will be appreciated.
I'm trying to make a quiz game.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

namespace QuizApp3
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private TextView titlescore;
    private Button sgame; // 25 questions
    private Button fgame; // 50 questions

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        titlescore = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TitleScore);
        sgame = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Sqgame);
        fgame = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Fqgame);

        sgame.Click += Sgame_Click;
        fgame.Click += Fgame_Click;

    }

    private void Fgame_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(QuestionActivity));
        Intent.PutExtra("Arr50", 50);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private void Sgame_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(QuestionActivity));
        Intent.PutExtra("Arr25", 25);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }


    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you mean `intent.PutExtra()` - what you posted is using capital "I" which is wrong.  And where is the code where you attempt to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

chang your line

```
    Intent.PutExtra("Arr50", 50);
    //to
    intent.PutExtra("Arr50", "50");
```

and add this line in QuestionActivity below SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity);

```
 string Arr50 = Intent.GetStringExtra("Arr50");
```